# Intersection within Object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some objects added to an Object3D (for grouping elements) and I'm trying to detect clicks on it.
My scene has a size of `600x400`, my camera is within a three-object and my event handler code looks like below:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var mouse = {};
   mouse.x = ( event.clientX / 600 ) * 2 - 1;
   mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / 400 ) * 2 + 1;

   var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
   projector.unprojectVector( vector, three.camera );

   var ray = new THREE.Ray( three.camera.position, vector.subSelf( three.camera.position ).normalize() );

   var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( group.children );
   alert(intersects.length);
   [...]
}
```

Actually I'm alerting the count of intersected objects. But it stays zero. It couldn't find any intersected objects. I've already played a bit aroud with the x, y and z values of my projection vector - without success.

I've added a stripped down sample for demonstrating this issue on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9svk/). Maybe someone has a short hint for me what goes wrong with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your fiddle, because you are calling `THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( )`, which creates a hierarchical structure, you need to add the recursive flag to `ray.intersectObjects()`.

```
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( group.children, true );
```

EDiT: `ray` is now an instance of `THREE.Raycaster` -- not `THREE.Ray`.

three.js r.58

Comment: Ah okay - thank you very much! But now it detects all 3 Cubes as one single object. I've also tried to use a custom object array and added the cubes - But the result is the same. Is there a way to detect every single cube?

Comment: Can you make a new post and explain you new issue in more detail?

Comment: I've found the solution: All MultiMaterialObjects had the same instance of material, so a change of material color has affected all objects. So now its clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: A side not for people reading this the Ray function, at least for this use case, is now called Raycaster

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and WestLangley's answer provides the answer. Great job! For anybody struggling with mouse selection of objects grouped in Object3D wrapper too, I am posting my own solution.

First, I created an array of objects that are selectable - I hope this also saves some performance, as RayCaster doesnt need to search all objects in the scene, but only those you wish to respond to selection. I also attached this array to scene object directly (solely for the fact that it is already accessible from most parts of my app)

```
scene.selectable = [];
```

Next step is to push all objects that you wish to make selectable into this array. You will insert only meshes/sprites/etc from your group, not the whole group. Only last line is important here:

```
var myWrapper = new THREE.Object3D();
var myObject = new THREE.Mesh( something );
myWrapper.add( myObject );
scene.add ( myWrapper );
scene.selectable.push( myObject );
```

And lastly in your mouse selection routine you will call raycaster like this:

```
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.selectable );
```