# How to find intersect with Object3d in Three js?

Tags: three.js

I have a json model exported from Revit using [RvtVa3c](https://github.com/va3c/RvtVa3c). I added the model to the scene using ObjectLoader.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader(manager);
loader.load( 'mesa.js', function ( object ) {
  scene.add(object);
}
```

Then I tried both...

```
// From Va3cViewer.js
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( targetList );
```

and...

```
// From three js example code 
// have onMouseMove event and raycaster initialized elsewhere in the code
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

Both didn't find any intersect. I have read one post about calling computeFaceNormals() on geometry before trying to find intersect, but no children have geometry when I debugged the code. Is there no way to find intersect with object3d? Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Source [here](https://github.com/Fatman13/bim/blob/master/three11.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261053/intersection-within-object3d).

Adding the second argument of "true" seemed to do the trick.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( targetList, true );
```